# how to JQuery get full data from JSON array

Tags: json, ajax, vb.net, each

how to fix when trying get json data but showing one record

```
{"d":[{"__type":"Tolu+mirex_tbl_amsfile","SITEID":"366","ARRIVALAIRPORT":"","WAYBILLORIGINATOR":"","AIRLINEPREFIX":"","AWBSERIALNUMBER":"","HOUSEAWB":"","MASTERAWBINDICATOR":"","ORIGINAIRPORT":"","PIECES":"1","WEIGHTCODE":"K","WEIGHT":"30,00","DESCRIPTION":"mouse","FDAINDICATOR":"","IMPORTINGCARRIER":"","FLIGHTNUMBER":"","ARRIVALDAY":"","ARRIVALMONTH":"","SHIPPERNAME":"TEST","SHIPPERSTREETADDRESS":"TEST","SHIPPERCITY":"Antalya","SHIPPERSTATEORPROVINCE":"Alanya","SHIPPERPOSTALCODE":"07400","SHIPPERCOUNTRY":"TR","SHIPPERTELEPHONE":"1","CONSIGNEENAME":"ARZU","CONSIGNEESTREETADDRESS":"LIMAN MAH","CONSIGNEECITY":"","CONSIGNEESTATEORPROVINCE":"","CONSIGNEEPOSTALCODE":"34100","CONSIGNEECOUNTRY":"TR","CONSIGNEETELEPHONE":"02124310707","AMENDMENTFLAG":"","AMENDMENTCODE":"21","AMENDMENTREASON":"","PTPDESTINATION":"","PTPDESTINATIONDAY":"","PTPDESTINATIONMONTH":"","BOARDEDPIECES":"","BOARDEDWEIGHTCODE":"","BORDEDWEIGHT":"","PARTIALSHIPMENTREF":"","BROKERCODE":"","INBONDDESTINATION":"","INBONDDESTINATIONTYPE":"","BONDEDCARRIERID":"","ONWARDCARRIER":"","BONDEDPREMISESID":"","TRANSFERCONTROLNUMBER":"","ENTRYTYPE":"","ENTRYNUMBER":"","COUNTRYOFORIGIN":"Afghanista","CUSTOMSVALUE":"25,00","CURRENCYCODE":"USD","HTSNUMBER":"","EXPRESSRELEASE":"Y"},{"__type":"Tolu+mirex_tbl_amsfile","SITEID":"367","ARRIVALAIRPORT":"","WAYBILLORIGINATOR":"","AIRLINEPREFIX":"","AWBSERIALNUMBER":"","HOUSEAWB":"","MASTERAWBINDICATOR":"","ORIGINAIRPORT":"","PIECES":"1","WEIGHTCODE":"K","WEIGHT":"30,00","DESCRIPTION":"mouse","FDAINDICATOR":"","IMPORTINGCARRIER":"","FLIGHTNUMBER":"","ARRIVALDAY":"","ARRIVALMONTH":"","SHIPPERNAME":"TEST","SHIPPERSTREETADDRESS":"TEST","SHIPPERCITY":"Antalya","SHIPPERSTATEORPROVINCE":"Alanya","SHIPPERPOSTALCODE":"07400","SHIPPERCOUNTRY":"TR","SHIPPERTELEPHONE":"1","CONSIGNEENAME":"ARZU","CONSIGNEESTREETADDRESS":"LIMAN MAH","CONSIGNEECITY":"","CONSIGNEESTATEORPROVINCE":"","CONSIGNEEPOSTALCODE":"34100","CONSIGNEECOUNTRY":"TR","CONSIGNEETELEPHONE":"02124310707","AMENDMENTFLAG":"","AMENDMENTCODE":"21","AMENDMENTREASON":"","PTPDESTINATION":"","PTPDESTINATIONDAY":"","PTPDESTINATIONMONTH":"","BOARDEDPIECES":"","BOARDEDWEIGHTCODE":"","BORDEDWEIGHT":"","PARTIALSHIPMENTREF":"","BROKERCODE":"","INBONDDESTINATION":"","INBONDDESTINATIONTYPE":"","BONDEDCARRIERID":"","ONWARDCARRIER":"","BONDEDPREMISESID":"","TRANSFERCONTROLNUMBER":"","ENTRYTYPE":"","ENTRYNUMBER":"","COUNTRYOFORIGIN":"Afghanista","CUSTOMSVALUE":"25,00","CURRENCYCODE":"USD","HTSNUMBER":"","EXPRESSRELEASE":"Y"},{"__type":"Tolu+mirex_tbl_amsfile","SITEID":"368","ARRIVALAIRPORT":"","WAYBILLORIGINATOR":"","AIRLINEPREFIX":"","AWBSERIALNUMBER":"","HOUSEAWB":"","MASTERAWBINDICATOR":"","ORIGINAIRPORT":"","PIECES":"1","WEIGHTCODE":"K","WEIGHT":"30,00","DESCRIPTION":"mouse","FDAINDICATOR":"","IMPORTINGCARRIER":"","FLIGHTNUMBER":"","ARRIVALDAY":"","ARRIVALMONTH":"","SHIPPERNAME":"TEST","SHIPPERSTREETADDRESS":"TEST","SHIPPERCITY":"Antalya","SHIPPERSTATEORPROVINCE":"Alanya","SHIPPERPOSTALCODE":"07400","SHIPPERCOUNTRY":"TR","SHIPPERTELEPHONE":"1","CONSIGNEENAME":"ARZU","CONSIGNEESTREETADDRESS":"LIMAN MAH","CONSIGNEECITY":"","CONSIGNEESTATEORPROVINCE":"","CONSIGNEEPOSTALCODE":"34100","CONSIGNEECOUNTRY":"TR","CONSIGNEETELEPHONE":"02124310707","AMENDMENTFLAG":"","AMENDMENTCODE":"21","AMENDMENTREASON":"","PTPDESTINATION":"","PTPDESTINATIONDAY":"","PTPDESTINATIONMONTH":"","BOARDEDPIECES":"","BOARDEDWEIGHTCODE":"","BORDEDWEIGHT":"","PARTIALSHIPMENTREF":"","BROKERCODE":"","INBONDDESTINATION":"","INBONDDESTINATIONTYPE":"","BONDEDCARRIERID":"","ONWARDCARRIER":"","BONDEDPREMISESID":"","TRANSFERCONTROLNUMBER":"","ENTRYTYPE":"","ENTRYNUMBER":"","COUNTRYOFORIGIN":"Afghanista","CUSTOMSVALUE":"25,00","CURRENCYCODE":"USD","HTSNUMBER":"","EXPRESSRELEASE":"Y"},{"__type":"Tolu+mirex_tbl_amsfile","SITEID":"369","ARRIVALAIRPORT":"","WAYBILLORIGINATOR":"","AIRLINEPREFIX":"","AWBSERIALNUMBER":"","HOUSEAWB":"","MASTERAWBINDICATOR":"","ORIGINAIRPORT":"","PIECES":"1","WEIGHTCODE":"K","WEIGHT":"30,00","DESCRIPTION":"mouse","FDAINDICATOR":"","IMPORTINGCARRIER":"","FLIGHTNUMBER":"","ARRIVALDAY":"","ARRIVALMONTH":"","SHIPPERNAME":"","SHIPPERSTREETADDRESS":"","SHIPPERCITY":"","SHIPPERSTATEORPROVINCE":"","SHIPPERPOSTALCODE":"","SHIPPERCOUNTRY":"","SHIPPERTELEPHONE":"","CONSIGNEENAME":"ARZU","CONSIGNEESTREETADDRESS":"LIMAN MAH","CONSIGNEECITY":"","CONSIGNEESTATEORPROVINCE":"","CONSIGNEEPOSTALCODE":"34100","CONSIGNEECOUNTRY":"TR","CONSIGNEETELEPHONE":"02124310707","AMENDMENTFLAG":"","AMENDMENTCODE":"21","AMENDMENTREASON":"","PTPDESTINATION":"","PTPDESTINATIONDAY":"","PTPDESTINATIONMONTH":"","BOARDEDPIECES":"","BOARDEDWEIGHTCODE":"","BORDEDWEIGHT":"","PARTIALSHIPMENTREF":"","BROKERCODE":"","INBONDDESTINATION":"","INBONDDESTINATIONTYPE":"","BONDEDCARRIERID":"","ONWARDCARRIER":"","BONDEDPREMISESID":"","TRANSFERCONTROLNUMBER":"","ENTRYTYPE":"","ENTRYNUMBER":"","COUNTRYOFORIGIN":"Afghanista","CUSTOMSVALUE":"25,00","CURRENCYCODE":"USD","HTSNUMBER":"","EXPRESSRELEASE":"Y"}]}
```

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Tolu.asmx/ams_file',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {

                    $.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
                        dataArray = [{
                            SITEID: value.SITEID,
                            ARRIVALAIRPORT: value.ARRIVALAIRPORT,
                            WAYBILLORIGINATOR: value.WAYBILLORIGINATOR,
                            AIRLINEPREFIX: value.AIRLINEPREFIX,
                            AWBSERIALNUMBER: value.AWBSERIALNUMBER,
                            HOUSEAWB: value.HOUSEAWB,
                            MASTERAWBINDICATOR: value.MASTERAWBINDICATOR,
                            ORIGINAIRPORT: value.ORIGINAIRPORT,
                            PIECES: value.PIECES,
                            WEIGHTCODE: value.WEIGHTCODE,
                            WEIGHT: value.WEIGHT,
                            DESCRIPTION: value.DESCRIPTION,
                            FDAINDICATOR: value.FDAINDICATOR,
                            IMPORTINGCARRIER: value.IMPORTINGCARRIER,
                            FLIGHTNUMBER: value.FLIGHTNUMBER,
                            ARRIVALDAY: value.ARRIVALDAY,
                            ARRIVALMONTH: value.ARRIVALMONTH,
                            SHIPPERNAME: value.SHIPPERNAME,
                            SHIPPERSTREETADDRESS: value.SHIPPERSTREETADDRESS,
                            SHIPPERCITY: value.SHIPPERCITY,
                            SHIPPERSTATEORPROVINCE: value.SHIPPERSTATEORPROVINCE,
                            SHIPPERPOSTALCODE: value.SHIPPERPOSTALCODE,
                            SHIPPERCOUNTRY: value.SHIPPERCOUNTRY,
                            SHIPPERTELEPHONE: value.SHIPPERTELEPHONE,
                            CONSIGNEENAME: value.CONSIGNEENAME,
                            CONSIGNEESTREETADDRESS: value.CONSIGNEESTREETADDRESS,
                            CONSIGNEECITY: value.CONSIGNEECITY,
                            CONSIGNEESTATEORPROVINCE: value.CONSIGNEESTATEORPROVINCE,
                            CONSIGNEEPOSTALCODE: value.CONSIGNEEPOSTALCODE,
                            CONSIGNEECOUNTRY: value.CONSIGNEECOUNTRY,
                            CONSIGNEETELEPHONE: value.CONSIGNEETELEPHONE,
                            AMENDMENTFLAG: value.AMENDMENTFLAG,
                            AMENDMENTCODE: value.AMENDMENTCODE,
                            AMENDMENTREASON: value.AMENDMENTREASON,
                            PTPDESTINATION: value.PTPDESTINATION,
                            PTPDESTINATIONDAY: value.PTPDESTINATIONDAY,
                            PTPDESTINATIONMONTH: value.PTPDESTINATIONMONTH,
                            BOARDEDPIECES: value.BOARDEDPIECES,
                            BOARDEDWEIGHTCODE: value.BOARDEDWEIGHTCODE,
                            BORDEDWEIGHT: value.BORDEDWEIGHT,
                            PARTIALSHIPMENTREF: value.PARTIALSHIPMENTREF,
                            BROKERCODE: value.BROKERCODE,
                            INBONDDESTINATION: value.INBONDDESTINATION,
                            INBONDDESTINATIONTYPE: value.INBONDDESTINATIONTYPE,
                            BONDEDCARRIERID: value.BONDEDCARRIERID,
                            ONWARDCARRIER: value.ONWARDCARRIER,
                            BONDEDPREMISESID: value.BONDEDPREMISESID,
                            TRANSFERCONTROLNUMBER: value.TRANSFERCONTROLNUMBER,
                            ENTRYTYPE: value.ENTRYTYPE,
                            ENTRYNUMBER: value.ENTRYNUMBER,
                            COUNTRYOFORIGIN: value.COUNTRYOFORIGIN,
                            CUSTOMSVALUE: value.CUSTOMSVALUE,
                            CURRENCYCODE: value.CURRENCYCODE,
                            HTSNUMBER: value.HTSNUMBER,
                            EXPRESSRELEASE: value.EXPRESSRELEASE
                        }];

                    })
                    $("#sonuc").html(JSON.stringify(dataArray));
                },

                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }

            })
```

i need full record array

RESULT ;

```
[{"SITEID":"369","ARRIVALAIRPORT":"","WAYBILLORIGINATOR":"","AIRLINEPREFIX":"","AWBSERIALNUMBER":"","HOUSEAWB":"","MASTERAWBINDICATOR":"","ORIGINAIRPORT":"","PIECES":"1","WEIGHTCODE":"K","WEIGHT":"30,00","DESCRIPTION":"mouse","FDAINDICATOR":"","IMPORTINGCARRIER":"","FLIGHTNUMBER":"","ARRIVALDAY":"","ARRIVALMONTH":"","SHIPPERNAME":"","SHIPPERSTREETADDRESS":"","SHIPPERCITY":"","SHIPPERSTATEORPROVINCE":"","SHIPPERPOSTALCODE":"","SHIPPERCOUNTRY":"","SHIPPERTELEPHONE":"","CONSIGNEENAME":"ARZU","CONSIGNEESTREETADDRESS":"LIMAN MAH","CONSIGNEECITY":"","CONSIGNEESTATEORPROVINCE":"","CONSIGNEEPOSTALCODE":"34100","CONSIGNEECOUNTRY":"TR","CONSIGNEETELEPHONE":"02124310707","AMENDMENTFLAG":"","AMENDMENTCODE":"21","AMENDMENTREASON":"","PTPDESTINATION":"","PTPDESTINATIONDAY":"","PTPDESTINATIONMONTH":"","BOARDEDPIECES":"","BOARDEDWEIGHTCODE":"","BORDEDWEIGHT":"","PARTIALSHIPMENTREF":"","BROKERCODE":"","INBONDDESTINATION":"","INBONDDESTINATIONTYPE":"","BONDEDCARRIERID":"","ONWARDCARRIER":"","BONDEDPREMISESID":"","TRANSFERCONTROLNUMBER":"","ENTRYTYPE":"","ENTRYNUMBER":"","COUNTRYOFORIGIN":"Afghanista","CUSTOMSVALUE":"25,00","CURRENCYCODE":"USD","HTSNUMBER":"","EXPRESSRELEASE":"Y"}]
```

Comment: **…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem**. Read [how to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

While processing the response, you are replacing the `dataArray` in the loop. Instead, append each record to the `dataArray`. Do the following:

```
dataArray = []
$.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
            dataArray.push({
                SITEID: value.SITEID,
                ARRIVALAIRPORT: value.ARRIVALAIRPORT,
                ....
             });
             ....
 })
```

Since I can't execute your code, here is the simple runnable code for illustration.

**What you are doing:**

```js
dataArray = []
response = [1, 2, 3, 4]
response.forEach(element => {
    dataArray=[{x:element}];
});
console.log(dataArray)
```

**What you want to do:**

```js
dataArray = []
response = [1, 2, 3, 4]
response.forEach(element => {
    dataArray.push({x: element});
});
console.log(dataArray)
```

Comment: @AliTolu Glad to know that your problem is resolved. Please do not forget to accept the answer and/or upvote :)